# How to append table after specific text in google docs using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to append table to google doc after specific text. Here is my attempt.

```
 var body = somedoc.getBody();   
    var range = body.findText("#PLACEHOLDER#");
    body.appendTable(data);
```

Here data is some multidimensional array. This works fine. But table gets appended at the end of body. I want to append table after '#PLACEHOLDER#'.

```
 var body = somedoc.getBody();   
    var range = body.findText("#PLACEHOLDER#");
    range.appendTable(data);
```

This doesn't work. How to get position of range (text: #PLACEHOLDER#)  and append table after it?

Comment: What does `findText()` return according to documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You want to insert a table after the text of `#PLACEHOLDER#` in Google Document.

  - From your question, I thought that `#PLACEHOLDER#` is put to a paragraph, and the paragraph includes only the text of `#PLACEHOLDER#`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

### Pattern 1:

When there is only one text of `#PLACEHOLDER#` in the Google Document, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var body = somedoc.getBody();
var range = body.findText("#PLACEHOLDER#");

// I added below script.
var ele = range.getElement();
if (ele.getParent().getParent().getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.BODY_SECTION) {
  var offset = body.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());
  body.insertTable(offset + 1, data);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

When there is multiple texts of `#PLACEHOLDER#` in the Google Document, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var body = somedoc.getBody();
var range = body.findText("#PLACEHOLDER#");

// I added below script.
while (range) {
  var ele = range.getElement();
  if (ele.getParent().getParent().getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.BODY_SECTION) {
    var offset = body.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());
    body.insertTable(offset + 1, data);
  }
  range = body.findText("#PLACEHOLDER#", range);
}
```

### Note:

- These modified scripts suppose that `data` is `table` or 2 dimensional array.

### References:

- [getChildIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildindexchild)
- [insertTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertTable(Integer,String))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample Document you want to use? By this, I would like to confirm the issue.